# How to parse Api having filters

Tags: java, android, api

I am having an API like the following:

```
 /homes/houses/?furnish_type=full,semi&house_type=independent,villa,apartment&accomodation_allowed=girls,boys,...
```

I want to set `filters` to remove boys or girls depending on the filter. How can I do this?
I am new to **Android** and APIs.

Comment: please give more detail of your question. what do you mean by "set filters"? what library is using? (retrofit, volley or ...)

Comment: That's going to completely depend on the author of the actual API.  There's not a standard way of specifying filters across all URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you would construct the API URL dynamically, and string together the appropriate filters.  So, to filter for just boys, or just girls, you would string the URLs together differently, like so:

```
/homes/houses/?furnish_type=full,semi&house_type=independent,villa,apartment&accomodation_allowed=boys

/homes/houses/?furnish_type=full,semi&house_type=independent,villa,apartment&accomodation_allowed=girls
```